# Wordpress nginx redirect not working(two wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

Wordpress nginx redirect not working
My folder structure

Eg:

techno->main folder 1st wordpress
inside of techno folder i created blog folder -> 2nd wordpress

So i want redirect blog wp pages to main wordpress.
like:

http://dev.demo.com/techno/blog/white-papers   to  http://dev.demo.com/techno/white-papers

or

http://dev.demo.com/techno/blog/white-papers   to  http://dev.demo.com/techno/resource/white-papers

it's always redirect 404 page not found.
My nginx config:

```
location /techno/blog/ {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /techno/blog/index.php?$args;
        rewrite /techno/blog/white-papers/$ /techno/white-papers redirect;
}
location /techno {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /techno/index.php?$args;
}
```

Comment: you need to post your configuration setup.  and specify what you mean by 'not working'.  "Bad Gateway"?  "Not found"?  etc..

Comment: it's always redirect 404 page.